# Conditional row removal

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel table:

```
Letter  Number
A       15
A       2212
A       3741
B       251
B       7
B       14201
C       13503
C       97
C       113
```

I would like to go through the "letter column" and whenever there is the same letter, look at the "number column" beside it and **delete the smaller values - keeping only the largest values**.

I would like the end result to have only one entry for each letter and the corresponding value next to it as shown below:

```
Letter  Number
A       3741
B       14201
C       13503
```

Comment: Can you sort? If so, you could sort the table based on the numbers, and delete all except the last row of each group.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorting is a viable option if the sample size was fairly small. However the data which I am working with has over 500+ different ""groups" - this will be very time consuming.

Comment: Does it have to be a macro? Pivot tables are great for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If your letters are in column A and numbers are in column B, the following code should do the trick:

```
Sub FindMaxValue()

Dim CountLng As Long

'find range
CountLng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'loop through range to find max
For x1 = CountLng To 2 Step -1
    For x2 = 2 To CountLng
        If Range("A" & x1).Value = Range("A" & x2).Value And x1 <> x2 Then
            If Range("B" & x1).Value >= Range("B" & x2).Value Then
                Rows(x2).EntireRow.Delete
                Exit for
            Else
                Rows(x1).EntireRow.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next x2
Next x1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Dictionary` to hold each letter maximum value and then `AutoFilter()` to delete "lower" values letter rows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub min()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim key As Variant

    Set rng = Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1)
            If .Exists(cell.value) Then
                If cell.Offset(, 1) > .item(cell.value) Then .item(cell.value) = cell.Offset(, 1).value
            Else
                .Add cell.value, cell.Offset(, 1).value
            End If
        Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For Each key In .Keys
            rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=key
            rng.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="<" & .item(key)
            rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
            rng.AutoFilter
        Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```